# How do i add new information into the same cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add more than one information in just one cell but i haven't figured out how. i don't want the information to change, i want the cell to keep both informations written.

Basically i have a tick box for each line and a button that will instantly click only the positive outcomes. after that, it prompts the user for a serial number which will be written on a cell. the number is unique for each person and i want to keep a record of more than 1 number so i know everyone who took a certain outcome.
example is person number 44 takes an outcome, "44" gets written on the cell. then person number 55 also takes the same outcome, "55" gets written alongside the already written 44 instead of replacing it.

```
VarNUMCB = InputBox("Insert User ID Number")

If Range("h3").Value >= 0 Then
   Range("j3").Value = VarNUMCB
Else
End If
```

Comment: `Range("j3").Value = Range("j3").Value & vbnewline & VarNUMCB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to amend a string to a content in a cell, just do so with the `"&"` character. Furthermore, you can define a delimeter separating the two entries (some specific character or a new line). In the below example I use `";"` as the delimeter

```
VarNUMCB = InputBox("Insert User ID Number")

If Range("h3").Value >= 0 Then    
    Range("j3").Value = Range("j3").Value & ";" & VarNUMCB 
Else
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare "VarNUMCB" variable. You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub trst()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Refer to sheet you are coding. Change sheet name if needed

        VarNUMCB = InputBox("Insert User ID Number")

        If .Range("H3").Value >= 0 Then '<- Use "." before range to make sure that your are targeting the sheet used in  the "With statement"
            .Range("J3").Value = .Range("J3").Value & " " & VarNUMCB '<- J3 value with a following by a space and the value VarNUMCB
        Else
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```